# How do i update two divs with once call java script function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to update my page details without refreshing the page, and i do it almost done!!
But i got the problem that a second div don't updates, it just happens for sometimes. so, i've got confused. Is there something wrong with `updatediv()` function?
Help or suggests. Thank you.

JAVA SCRIPT

```
function updatediv(postid) {

  //Change button to like or unlike
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("likebutton"+postid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","likebutton.php?id="+postid,true);
  xmlhttp.send();


  //Count likes and update to #likestatus div
  //My problems is HERE sometimes work sometimes doesn't work

  var xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("likestatus"+postid).innerHTML=xmlhttp2.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp2.open("GET","likestatus.php?id="+postid,true);
  xmlhttp2.send();
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="likestatus<? echo $postid; ?>" onclick="updatediv(<? echo $postid; ?>)">Like</a>
<div id="likestatus<? echo $postid; ?>">0 like this</div>
```

Comment: where do you define `str` ?

Comment: i think something wrong with `"likestatus.php?mode="+1+"&id="+str`

Comment: sorry, it was wrong i have edited.

Comment: One problem I see is that the id attribute needs to be unique across the whole document. Please see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id
Perhaps you could refer to the elements you'd like to update by class name instead and use getElementsByClassName

Comment: @user3695637 what is the response of `alert(xmlhttp2.responseText);`

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti count for current likes of post ex. `3 likes this`

Comment: i can't see any problem with `document.getElementById("likestatus"+postid).innerHTML`

Comment: @user3695637 then try jquery ;)

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti  my code is correct, but its works sometimes. i think it should have another way. but how?